# If $f(x) = (a - x)/(a + x)$ and $f\circ f(x) = x$, find $f(-1/2)$

Tags: functions

**Original Problem**

For a suitably chosen real constant $a$, let a function, $f : \Bbb R\backslash\{–a\} → \Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x) = (a - x)/(a + x)$. Further suppose that for any real number $x ≠-a$ and $f(x) ≠ -a$, $(f\circ f)(x) = x$. Then $f(-1/2)$ is equal to:

(a) $~1/3$

(b) $~3$

(c) $~-3$

(d) $~-1/3$

**My Progress**:

Given $f\circ f(x) = x$. Hence, by putting the expression of  $f(x)$ in place of $x$ inside $f$, and equating to $x$, I get:

$a(a – 1) + x(1 – a^2) + x^2(1-a) = 0$

However, I am unable to proceed further. The answer given is option- (b). Please help that how can I continue further. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: note that the equation “$a(a-1)+x(1-a^2)+x^2(1-a)=0$“ holds for all $x\neq{-a}$ and $f(x)\neq{-a}$. Also, observe that $1-a^2=(1-a)(1+a)$. What does this suggest about the value of $a$?

Comment: @Explorer1234 Thanks. I did made a quadratic in $a$ , but the discriminant is not factorisable.

Comment: @An_Elephant A (quadratic) polynomial having infinitely many roots must be the zero polynomial. The coefficient of $x^2$ is $1-a$, so you get $a=1$ (and all other coefficients vanish as well).

Comment: @egreg Wow Thanks ! That's also a nice explanation.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $a$ cannot be zero. This allows taking $x = 0$, which gives you $f(0) = 1$. The second condition then implies that $f(1) = 0$, which leads to $a = 1$.

It follows that $f(-1/2) = 3$.

Comment: Thanks! If I put $a=3,10$ etc.then I get different quadratics and also many other values of $a$ also. How can I be sure that $a=1$ is only solution.

Comment: Because each coefficient of the binomial must be zero, since equality holds for all $x$!

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to set $f(x)$ and get $\dfrac{a-f(x)}{a+f(x)}=x$ which gives after simple calculations that:

$a^{2}+ax-a+x=xa^{2}+ax^{2}+ax-x^{2}$ which gives $a=1$ and therefore:

$f(x)=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$ and $f(-1/2)=3$ which is $(b)$. Your solution is correct!

Comment: Hi @George . But after that quadratic expression how you get $a = 1$ ?

Comment: @An_Elephant Okay, this won't work for everything, but in this case, on the right hand side we have $ax^2 - x^2$ and we don't have an $x^2$ term on the left so we can just say $a-1=0$ and therefore $a=1$.

Comment: Put everything on the left side and take each coefficient of the binomial equal to zero!

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos Yes, as I recently learnt ,to do this because that polynomial is zero ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that your quadratic equality is an *identity* that is true for *all* $x$ in the domain. Which means it is true for $x = 1$ in particular.

With $x = 1$, you get $a(a-1) + 1-a^2 + 1-a = 0 \implies a = 1$.

Now use that $a$ value to finish up.

Comment: Hi, but what do you mean by identity here? And how?

Comment: @An_Elephant https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_(mathematics) Your functional definition is an identity that holds true for the entirety of the domain. Equations can be true for particular value(s) of the variable or true for *all* values in a given domain (and this is what an identity is). An example of the former is $x^2 = 4$, which only holds true for $x = \pm 2$. An example of the latter (an identity) is $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, which holds true for all real $x$. Since an identity holds true for the entire domain, you can pick "convenient" value(s) for the variable, as I did.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. But, If I put $a=3,10$ etc.then I get different quadratics and also many other values of $a$ also. How can I be sure that $a=1$ is only solution?

Comment: The factorisation is $(1-a)(x^2 + x(1+a) - a) = 0$. Since $a$ is a constant that is invariant with $x$, you should only look at the $x$-independent part of the left hand side, giving $a=1$.

Comment: Thanks but can't $a$ be a variable type constant like for example $a$ lies between interval etc like $(a,b)$ .

Comment: @An_Elephant What is a "variable type constant"? That sounds like an oxymoron.

Comment: Sorry. Hey, While solving it again and again, I found a solution. Should I post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for giving their kind and helpful solutions. I don't know if this is purely correct or not but while solving it again and again, I proceeded that :

$f(x)=\dfrac{a-x}{a+x}$

By pluggin $x=0$ , we get ;

$f(0)=\dfrac{a-0}{a+0} = 1$         (**Statement-1**)

Now, putting $x=0$ in this given condition: $f(f(x))$ = $x$ ,

Hence, $f(f(0))$ = $0$

$f(1) = 0$  (**using statement 1**)

Hence, $f(1)=\dfrac{a-1}{a+1} = 0$ ;

Hence, $a=1$ . And, it's easy now to evaluate that $f(-1/2)=3$